# Codename One Aligning components vertically over multiple rows

Tags: codenameone

I have a container that has within it some unknown number of components (which are actually also containers in which I have overridden calcPreferredSize to make them a consistent size).  Since the number of components may be > the number that can fit on a single line, there may be an overflow to line 2, etc.

I am using FlowLayout on the outer container, which works fine for one row.  But the second row is offset.

So where I want:

|.X.X.X.|
|.X.X.X.|

I actually get:

|.X.X.X.|
|X.X.X..|

where X is the component, dots are spacing, and |  are the sides of the container.

What is the best way to do this?  I assume FlowLayout does this because the left margin for the first element on row 2 is actually applied on the top row, so there is no margin remaining to push it away from the container border.

I have tried GridLayout, but I find the rightmost X component on each row is expanded beyond the preferred size I have set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by putting padding on the left side and top of the container, and then changing the component margin so that the margin is on the right and bottom, rather than the top and left.  This allows me to use FlowLayout on the container which is preferable as it does not alter the preferred size of the components in it.

So when flow layout puts a component on row 2, the container padding forces the component away from the "wall".

Padding and margin is like a puzzle...but there is usually a way to use it to get the look you want - I just had to do some thinking to get this right.

Answer (score 0):

Row spanning is the problem here. If you override `calcPreferredSize` you're effectively blocking the spanning from working properly as we need to allocate space for each component horizontally and vertically.

The problem is that layout is determined and then line breaks might need more space (vertically) but layout was already set. The only solution for this is reflow (or multiple-passes) which we don't "really" support as it includes a serious performance overhead.

Grid layout will set everything to the same size. A table layout might be a better choice. I suggest not overriding `calcPreferredSize()` and instead just using 50% as the width of the table columns.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried Table layout originally, though that was a couple weeks ago and I honestly cannot remember exactly what I could not get to work for me - I think it was the same as the grid problem in that the components expanded beyond the preferred size I was setting.  Once I got around to trying this today, I had already worked out the other solution I added as an answer, which solved the problem.  I do need to keep the component sizing consistent as it is a graphical element that can show up in multiple places in the screen.